Want a different order than permutation
I have a list: {8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5}
I want to get all sequential numbers (forwards and backwards) out of this, hence in the output I like to have: (with dupes removed)
8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 81, 812, 8127, 81273, 812733, 8127335, 12, 127, 1273, 12733, 127335, 27,.....35, 5

And the backwards version included in output also:
5, 53, 533, 5337, ....,5337218,....., 18, 8

Then sort the list and remove dupes!
There ust be an easy way to do this.
Thanks!

Why does it not begin {8,81,812,...}?

Doesn't matter what it begins with....i just put all the single digits first, followed by 2-digits, then 3's etc...   rather ad-hoc after that, as long as we get all, then sorted

Using Subsequences:
subs = Subsequences[list, {1, Infinity}];
rev = Reverse /@ subs;
Union[FromDigits /@ subs, FromDigits /@ rev]


{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12, 18, 21, 27, 33, 35, 37, 53, 72, 73, 81, 127,  218, 273, 335, 337, 372, 533, 721, 733, 812, 1273, 2733, 3372, 3721,  5337, 7218, 7335, 8127, 12733, 27335, 33721, 37218, 53372, 81273, 127335, 337218, 533721, 812733, 5337218, 8127335}

Or as a function:
generateIntegerSubsets[list_List] := Module[{subs, rev},
  subs = Subsequences[list, {1, Infinity}];
  rev = Reverse /@ subs;
  Union[FromDigits /@ subs, FromDigits /@ rev]
  ]


Elegant....Thanks!

list={8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5};rlist=Reverse[list];
Sort[Map[FromDigits,DeleteDuplicates[
  Reap[
    For[len=1,len<=7,len++,For[pos=1,pos<=7-len+1,pos++,Sow[Take[list,{pos,pos+len-1}]]]]
    For[len=1,len<=7,len++,For[pos=1,pos<=7-len+1,pos++,Sow[Take[rlist,{pos,pos+len-1}]]]]
  ][[2,1]]]]]

OR
list={8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5};rlist=Reverse[list];
  Sort[Map[FromDigits,DeleteDuplicates[Reap[
    For[len=1,len<=7,len++,For[pos=1,pos<=7-len+1,pos++,
      Sow[Take[list,{pos,pos+len-1}]];Sow[Take[rlist,{pos,pos+len-1}]]
  ]]][[2,1]]]]]

OR
f[list_]:=Module[{len,pos,rlist=Reverse[list]},
  Sort[Map[FromDigits,DeleteDuplicates[Reap[
    For[len=1,len<=Length[list],len++,For[pos=1,pos<=Length[list]-len+1,pos++,
      Sow[Take[list,{pos,pos+len-1}]];Sow[Take[rlist,{pos,pos+len-1}]]
  ]]][[2,1]]]]]];
f[{8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5}]

OR
(* Shorter,simpler,faster.
   match=search[list];
   Join[match,search[Reverse[list]]==Join[match,Reverse[match]] *) 
f[list_]:=Module[{len,pos,match},
  match=Flatten[Table[Take[list,{pos,pos+len-1}],{len,Length[list]},{pos,Length[list]-len+1}],1];
  Union[FromDigits/@Join[match,Reverse/@match]]]
f[{8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5}]

{1,2,3,5,7,8,12,18,21,27,33,35,37,53,72,73,81,127,218,273,335,
337,372,533,721,733,812,1273,2733,3372,3721,5337,7218,7335,8127,
12733,27335,33721,37218,53372,81273,127335,337218,533721,812733,
5337218,8127335}


There is no internal function to simplify this more? .... So say my list is of varying length, I guess I can pass Length[list] instead of 7..

Also, how can I made this into a function:  DigitSeq[x_] := list = x; rlist = Reverse[list];
Sort[ .....etc.... Length[x] ....

There is a very old joke or pun that says there are always at least ten different ways of doing anything in Mathematica and that at least one or two of those are almost completely incomprehensible. So far we only have seen two ways of doing this and I am not sure whether this question has the right flavor to bring out the truly fiendish answer, but there is still time and you might get there. BUT, with the fiendish answers, you may need to ask yourself whether those are TRULY simpler or even more complicated. Would taking every 7 digit number and see if it is in your number be shorter code?

Thanks @Bill!  Totally agree....Can you also guide on how I can flip this into a function..Thx

This is NOT correct syntax, I can't quite think how to correct that syntax to make it work at the moment. but if that could be fixed then does this Select[MatchQ[{8,1,2,7,3,3,5},{___,#,___}]&,Table[IntegerDigits[n],{n,0,10^8-1}]] satisfy your urge for the simpler internal function that you want? The idea of that is to use pattern matching to find every n that appears inside your 7 digit number using as few characters of code as possible.

alist = {8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5};

ReplaceList[alist, {___, x__, ___} :> FromDigits[{x}]]


{8, 81, 812, 8127, 81273, 812733, 8127335, 1, 12, 127, 1273, 12733, 
127335, 2, 27, 273, 2733, 27335, 7, 73, 733, 7335, 3, 33, 335, 3, 35,
5}

ReplaceList[Reverse@alist, {___, x__, ___} :> FromDigits[{x}]]


{5, 53, 533, 5337, 53372, 533721, 5337218, 3, 33, 337, 3372, 33721, 
337218, 3, 37, 372, 3721, 37218, 7, 72, 721, 7218, 2, 21, 218, 1, 18,
8}


Brilliant, wow! I need to understand how it works still!

Problem with this is that it you pass in a list with 3 members or more, it won't work..not generic...unles you can make it generic into a Function?...Thx

Please add a concrete example (through a comment) of a list where this fails.

Apologies, I had an extra underscore in the middle parameter next to x!   Can you tell me what roles the undescores and their counts play...

Documentation is your friend. I interpret it as "give me a sequence of numbers from the list; calling it  x (of length at least 1 hence the two underscores) that is preceded and/or followed by another sequence (possibly of length 0 signified by three underscores) and then give me all such sequences".

list = {8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5};
n = Length@list;
Join[list, 
  Table[FromDigits /@ Table[Take[list, {j, i}], {i, j + 1, n}], {j, 1,
      n - 1}] // Catenate] // DeleteDuplicates


{8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 81, 812, 8127, 81273, 812733, 8127335, 12, 127, \ 1273, 12733, 127335, 27, 273, 2733, 27335, 73, 733, 7335, 33, 335, 35}


Thanks! Is there any simpler internal function to do this?   Would assume not!  Also 2 things: need dupes removed and also need this in reverse order also!

Perhaps uninspired:
s = {8, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 5};
d[u_] := 10^Range[Length[u] - 1, 0, -1] . u
With[{w = Length[s]},
 Union[s]~Join~Table[d[s[[1 ;; j]]], {j, 2, w}]~Join~
  Table[d[s[[w ;; w - j ;; -1]]], {j, 1, w - 1}]]

=>
{1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 81, 812, 8127, 81273, 812733, 8127335, 53, 533, \
5337, 53372, 533721, 5337218}

